# Magento 2.0.7 to 2.1 failed to upgrade

Tags: magento2

I executed the upgrade from the Magento backend, but the update process hang on setup:upgrade, which give me the following error:

[image]

Now the frontend is down and I cannot login to backend.
I tried to execute this command without success:

/bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: Hi Amin, I'm running PHP 7.0.6, from command line if I type php -v doesn't do anything, strange thing is that to invoke php from commandline I have to type php70 -v.

Comment: I'm using the patch as described here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html

Comment: Based on your comment: "I'm running PHP 7.0.6, from command line if I type php -v doesn't do anything" I think your PHP is not installed globally!

Comment: SOLVED
I wrongly renamed in Magento 2.0.7 the default attribute from Default to Generic, this was causing the update to not complete.

Comment: @MarcosLamba  In localhost how could you solve cron job?